# Errro when trying to copy from S3 using AWS CLI 2 the following arguments are required: paths

Tags: aws-cli

I am trying to download files from S3 bucket I am using AWS CLI 2 and I am getting the following error. Not sure what "paths" is

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/my-folder --exclude "*" --include "*2020-06*" --recursive --profile mfa --region us-east-1

usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: the following arguments are required: paths
```

Comment: You can try to use `s3api` instead. `aws s3api copy-object --copy-source bucket/folder/folder/folder/file --bucket my_bucket --key destination_bucket/folder/folder/folder/new_file_name`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usage of `aws s3 cp` is:

```
aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>
```

You need to specify your `<LocalPath>`, it should be:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/my-folder YOUR_LOCAL_PATH ...
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/my-folder . --exclude "*" --include "*2020-06*" --recursive --profile mfa --region us-east-1 had forgot to add "dot" for copying to current directory